# List Transactions that Meet Criteria

Tags: sql

Realizing that another question I asked before may be too difficult, I'm changing my requirements.

I work for a credit card company. Our database has a customer table and a transaction table. Fields in the customer table are SSN and CustomerKey. Fields in the transaction table are CustomerKey, transaction date (Transdate), and transaction amount (TransAmt).

I need a query that can identify each ssn where the sum of any of their transaction amounts > 1000 within a two day period in 2012. If a ssn has transaction amounts > 1000 within a two day period, I need the query to return ***all*** the transactions for that ssn.

Here is an example of the raw data in the Transaction Table:

```
Trans#-----CustKey-----Date--------Amount
1-----------12345----01/01/12--------$600
2-----------12345----01/02/12--------$500
3-----------67890----01/03/12--------$10
4-----------98765----04/01/12--------$600
5-----------43210----04/02/12--------$600
6-----------43210----04/03/12--------$100
7-----------13579----04/02/12--------$600
8-----------24568----04/03/12--------$100
```

Here is an example of the raw data in the Customer Table:

```
CustKey-----SSN
12345------123456789
67890------123456789
98765------987654321
43210------987654321
13579------246801357
24568------246801357
```

**Here are the results I need:**

```
Trans#------SSN---------Date---------Amount
1--------123456789----01/01/12---------$600
2--------123456789----01/02/12---------$500
3--------123456789----01/03/12----------$10
4--------987654321----04/01/12---------$600
5--------987654321----04/02/12---------$600
6--------987654321----04/03/12---------$100
```

As you can see in my results included ***all*** transactions for SSN 123456789 and 987654321, and excluded SSN 246801357.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Here's what I tried: select c.ssn, t.*
from TransDtl t
join Customer c on t.CustomerKey = c.CustomerKey
join(select c.ssn, SUM(t.TransAmt) as Total
     from TransDtl t
     join Customer c on t.CustomerKey = c.CustomerKey
  where t.postdate between '1/4/2012' and '1/7/2012'
  and TransDtlKey <= t.transdtlkey
  group by c.ssn
  having SUM(t.transamt) > 5000) x
on x.ssn = c.SSN
where t.postdate between '1/4/2012' and '1/7/2012'

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to roll through each two day period within a year. Here is an **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1743d/4)** example.
The idea is pretty simple:

1) Create a temp table to store all matching customers

```
create table CustomersToShow
(
    SSN int
)
```

2) Loop trough a year and populate temp table with customers that match the amount criteria

```
declare @firstDayOfTheYear datetime = '1/1/2012';
declare @lastDayOfTheYear datetime = '12/31/2012';
declare @currentDate datetime = @firstDayOfTheYear;
declare @amountThreshold money = 1000;

while @currentDate <= @lastDayOfTheYear
begin
    insert into CustomersToShow(SSN)
    select b.SSN
    from transactions a
        join customers b
        on a.CustKey = b.CustKey
    where TransactionDate >= @currentDate
        and TransactionDate <= DATEADD(day, 2, @currentDate)
    group by b.SSN  
    having SUM(a.TransactionAmount) >= @amountThreshold

    set @currentDate = DATEADD(day,2,@currentDate)
end
```

3) And then just select

```
select a.TransNumber, b.SSN, a.TransactionDate, a.TransactionAmount 
from transactions a
    join customers b
    on a.CustKey = b.CustKey
    join CustomersToShow c
    on b.SSN = c.SSN
```

**Note**: This will be slow...

Answer (score 0):

While you could probably come up with a hacky way to do this via standard SQL, this is a problem that IMO is more suited to being solved by code (i.e. not by set-based logic / SQL).

It would be easy to solve if you sort the transaction list by customerKey and date, then loop through the data.  Ideally I would do this in code, but alternatively you could write a stored procedure and use a loop and a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy and well-suited to set-based logic if you look at it right.  You simply need to join to a table that has every date range you're interested in.  Every T-SQL database (Oracle has it built-in) should have a utility table named `integers` - it's very useful surprisingly often:

```
CREATE TABLE integers ( n smallint, constraint PK_integers primary key clustered (n))
INSERT integers select top 1000 row_number() over (order by o.id) from sysobjects o cross join sysobjects
```

Your date table then looks like:

```
SELECT dateadd(day, n-1, '2012') AS dtFrom, dateadd(day, n+1, '2012') AS dtTo
from integers where n <= 366
```

You can then (abbreviating):

```
SELECT ssn, dtFrom
FROM yourTables t
    JOIN ( SELECT dateadd(day, n-1, '2012') as dtFrom, dateadd(day, n+1, '2012') AS dtTo
           from integers where n <= 366 ) d on t.date between d.dtFrom and d.dtTo
GROUP BY ssn, dtFrom
HAVING sum(amount) > 1000
```

You can select all your transactions:

```
WHERE ssn in ( SELECT distinct ssn from ( <above query> ) t )
```